# zsh: command not found: netlify on mac OS

Tags: reactjs, macos, create-react-app, netlify

I am trying to deploy basic react-app to netlify. I ran these commands to install and deploy application

- `npm install netlify-cli -g`
- `netlify deploy`

It throws:
`zsh: command not found: netlify` error.

I am working on mac OS. What is causing this issue?

Comment: can u check the path where `netlify-cli` is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It basically means your zshrc does not have npm binary directory in the PATH. Make sure that you have that squared away.

Are you using `brew` or `nvm` to install npm?

## Correction

You have to install netlify-cli as well. That gives you the netlify command.

`npm install -g netlify-cli`

Comment: I had used `brew` to install npm

Comment: yeah, need to install `netlify-cli` . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder:

```
/Users/<user>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/
```

And delete any files/folders pertaining to Netlify. For exmaple folder named:

```
netlify-cli
```

Then reinstall the cli using

```
npm install netlify-cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

**step 1:** re-run the netlify-cli installation command to get the path where cli is installed

**step 2:** test the version using the full path where the cli is installed, it'll confirm that `netlify-cli` is working

**step 3:** add the npm directory link to your zsh environment variable PATH

Answer (score 0):

- Use the main Terminal(not the integrated terminal of your text editor) when installing the netlify-cli.

  `npm install -g netlify-cli`

I had installed it multiple times in the integrated terminal of VS code but all in vain.Success came after using the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Or use `npx netlify login` for example, worked for me